why is the camera not following the player if phaser 3
I tried to get the camera to follow the player with this.cameras.startFollow(this.player) but it still did not work. it just shows a black screen, why is this?
I was expecting it to follow the player but it was not for some reason. I also tried to
camera = this.cameras.main; camera.startFollow(player); camera.setFollowOffset(-300, 225); camera.setLerp(0,0);
but it did not work. All of the things I tried ended up making the screen black.

the youtube videos teaching people this were either in typescript (completely different from javascript) or bogus videos that were used just to promote someones game.

I put all the code mentioned in the question at the end of the create function. Is this what I am supposed to do?

Here Some tipps fro asking question on Stackoverflow, write all the relevant information, in the question. (You can edit your question even after you posted it), adding more questions/information in comments makes answering difficult.  Post the relevant code, maybe a MRE checkout for more details https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . And If you ask a question and get an answer/comment, engage: comment, accept/vote and/or post better answer. Don't just take what you need and leave.

Basically your code seems correct (except maybe, that setting setLerp(0,0) would disable this feature, "...A value of zero will disable tracking on that axis..."), but without more context it could might be wrong.
(More Context could be: which Phaser version (3.80.1) are you using, relevant code, are there some errors in the code / browser console, ...).
That said,...
Usually a black screen is a sign for an error in the code. Check your browser console, to see if there are some javascript errors.
Here a small working demo for a camera following:
(this is a minimal reproducible example, for your question)


document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
    },
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Start is here')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    this.add.line(0, 0, 0, 0, config.width * 3, config.height, 0xffffff);
    
    this.player = this.add.rectangle( 20, 80, 10, 10, 0xffffff);
    
    this.physics.add.existing(this.player);
    
    this.player.body.setVelocityX(50);
    
    let camera = this.cameras.main; 
    camera.startFollow(this.player); 
    camera.setFollowOffset(-50, 15); 
    camera.setLerp(.005, .005);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>




Tipp: I would recommend checking the official phaser examples pages, if you want to know some details, or some new functions. Instead of watching videos. Phaser provides many examples and they are all pretty good and up-to-date.


I fixed it. It was a small bug in the update function destroying everything. Both of these methods work but please dont use setLerp.
